# Universal property quotient

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. A pair $(K, \pi: G \to K)$ where $\pi$ is a group morphism is said to satisfy the universal property of the quotient group if for all group morphisms $f: G \to H$ with $N \subseteq \ker f$ there is a unique $\tilde{f}: K \to H$ such that $\tilde{f}\circ \pi = f$.

**Question**: Is this definition correct? I believe we should also require  that $N \subseteq \ker \pi$, or does this maybe follow from the definition?

Comment: As stated, the pair $(G, 1_G)$ satisfies this. At the very least you would need to add that $\tilde{f}$ is unique.

Comment: @MorA. Your pair also satisfies the uniqueness requirement.

Comment: So I should ask for $N \subseteq \ker \pi$? Thanks!

Comment: I also meant the uniqueness and I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the condition that $N\subset \ker \pi$ should be added. Otherwise, any surjective morphism with $\ker\pi\subset N$ would satisfy the property.